# passing array of string from one class to another

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a string array from one class to another in my java code. By using code such as

```
Class instanceofclass = new Class();
String text1 = instanceofclass.variablename;
```

and then displaying it out on screen worked fine!

However I'm trying to get the array of a string. So in my first class I have

```
JButton [] FilmTime = new JButton[5];                       
JButton [] FilmNames = new JButton[8];
String [] films = new String [8];
DbConnector dataBase = new DbConnector();
for (int i =0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            films[i] = dataBase.FilmTitle[i];
        }
    for (int i =0; i<= 7; i++)
        {
            FilmNames[i] = new JButton (films[i] + " ("+age+")");
            FilmNames[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(563,50));

            grid.add(FilmNames[i]);
        }
```

I know I can use one for loop but I was just checking issues at the momment.

In my second class used named dbconnector i have:

```
public String FilmTitle [];
    for (int i =0; i<=7; i++)
                {
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE ID =" + i;
                    Rs = St.executeQuery(query);
                        while (Rs.next())
                        {   
                            FilmTitle[i] = Rs.getString("FilmName");

                        }
                }
```

Eclipse gives the error as:

```
Error is: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.init(main.java:46)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 46 is the statement in the first for loop...
testingme[i] = instanceofclass.variablename[i];

Comment: You haven't initialized `testingme`.

Comment: You've declared it as `String [] testingme;`, but you haven't initialized it `testingme = new String[8]`. I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: I carried out the edits and edited my post....same issue occurs

Comment: Arrays are 0-based, you might want to look at your for() loop conditions.

Comment: Did you add `FilmNames[i]`? Edit history says it was me but obviously I have no knowledge of what that should be; it got merged with my edit. What is it? And what is `instanceofclass.variablename[i]`?

Comment: Ah ... i guess its complaining for a out of bound expression...changed it to 0 -7 no luck still

Comment: @Bobski You may be able to get away with that in some cases but can't say for certain without seeing all of the code.

Comment: Edit your example in case it helps others help you

Comment: added more codes and the names i used

Comment: I don't see this line used anywhere:  testingme[i] = instanceofclass.variablename[i]

Comment: films[i] = dataBase.FilmTitle[i];

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize string array.

```
String[] testingme = new String[8];
```